# PHP Find Gaps over the course of N years across multiple date ranges

Tags: php, datetime, range

Taking a multidimensional array such as

```
array(
    array('begin' => '2006-01-01', 'finish' => '2006-02-28'),
    array('begin' => '2006-03-01', 'finish' => '2006-06-30'),
    array('begin' => '2006-08-01', 'finish' => '2007-12-30'),
    array('begin' => '2007-01-01', 'finish' => '2016-12-30'),
);
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to process Nth number of arrays with varying degrees of ranges and overlaps to see if there is an gaps over the course of N years. My current requirement is down to the month. But I simply can not currently wrap my head around this. Without going through a series of nested foreaches that ultimately paint me in a corner and are way to expensive to process on bigger data sets.

Comment: the N number of elements will be in order like in your example?

Comment: Not 100% guaranteed in order no. I may have to take an additional step to sort it somehow if need be I am ultimately looking for ideas or methods people have used previously to try and figure out what I need to do to achieve a similar goal

Comment: How exactly do you want the "gap" to be defined/returned in your example? Just "there is a gap yes/no" or "there are X gaps" or "there is a gap between 2006-06-30 and 2006-08-01"?

Comment: Idealy knowing what the gaps are so I can present them for UX needs, but at this point saying yes/no is something I can work with. I've been banging my head against the wall for a bit on this one trying think it through but Im either over thinking it, and its going to just be a lot more expensive than it should be, or its not going to give the results I want overall

Answer (score 0):

This code is hopefully in O(n) and assumes that it's an ordered array as in the example.

I used that this date format can be compared as strings and gives the same result, as if you'd worked with complex date objects.

```
// $a is your multidimensional array as above

$gap = array();
for($i=1; $i<sizeof($a); $i++){
   $gap[$i] = $a[$i-1]['finish'] < $a[$i]['begin'];
}
```

`$gap` contains an array or booleans, which indicate at which indexes there is a gap.

Comment: Yea these would be compared as strings, but I am open to any thoughs overall.

Comment: Do consecutive days count as a gap? (ends on 30th, starts on 31th for example) If not, I'm missing something here in my code.

Comment: I'd like them to, but down to the month at this point is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to suggest an actual implementation, but more a general approach.

You can usually look at this kind of problems two ways:

1. Make super smart code. Craft an algorithm that recursively merges the ranges that overlaps, leaving you with an array of discrete ranges. You have gaps if you have more than one row in the array, and the gaps are defined between the end of a range and the start of another one. The keyword here is *recursively*.
2. Make super dumb code. Build an assoc array with all the months of your interval (that can't be very much, even 10 years is only 120 months) as keys, and "true" as value. Iterate your array, and set the months that appears in a range to "false". Use `array_filter` and ta-dah! You're left with the months having gaps. The key here is to not use `date` related functions (they're slow) and instead just go at it arithmetically.

Hope this help putting you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Not widely tested and needs some refactoring, but this is the best algorithm I could come up with (I've done something similar with database actually):

```
define('DAY_SEC', 86400);
$result = [];
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $begin  = strtotime($date['begin']);
    $finish = strtotime($date['finish']);

    $merged = null;
    foreach ($result as $idx => $span) {
        if ($span['begin'] <= $finish + DAY_SEC && $span['finish'] >= $begin - DAY_SEC) {
            if (isset($merged)) {
                $min = min($span['begin'], $begin, $result[$merged]['begin']);
                $max = max($span['finish'], $finish, $result[$merged]['finish']);
                unset($result[$idx]);
            } else {
                $min = min($span['begin'], $begin);
                $max = max($span['finish'], $finish);
                $merged = $idx;
            }

            $result[$merged] = ['begin' => $min, 'finish' => $max];
        }
    }

    if (!isset($merged)) {
        $result[] = ['begin' => $begin, 'finish' => $finish];
    }
}

foreach ($result as &$span) {
    $span['begin'] = date('Y-m-d', $span['begin']);
    $span['finish'] = date('Y-m-d', $span['finish']);
}
```

It will result in array of continuous timespans. It adds timespans one by one and merges them when overlaping with all previously added. If it overlaps more than one period then it merges consecutive matches into the first one.